# Ubuntu 14.04 Firewall Issues - How to disable UFW

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw, vps

**EDIT: I can now confirm through the boot.log that UFW is automatically launching and enabling itself. How do I go about disabling it from SSH of another OS (Debian) as in what file do I edit to disable UFW.**

My ports are being filtered by ufw, proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRAM2.png
That is my domain name pointing to my VPS.

Is there a way to find out what firewall is blocking ports? I've already looked at UFW and that is disabled, I've also looked for iptables but that isn't installed or I don't know where it's installed.

I can not connect to my VPS because of it. Does anyone have possible firewalls I can look for? I'm currently running my VPS in "rescue-mode" so I have debian to work with. I just need to know the file locations of possible firewalls.

Thanks!

Comment: Tell us more about "can not connect to my VPS". I'm not persuaded it is a firewall issue. Which ports are you trying to access? Are there servers running for those ports?

Comment: You can see if `iptables` is installed or not with this command - `dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W | grep iptable` or `apt-cache policy iptables`

Comment: My VPS provider and I can confirm that it is a firewall because all ports are "filtered." http://i.imgur.com/fsEQx0T.png https://forums.quantumcraftnetwork.com is my domain. All ports are filtered and whatnot.

Comment: Updated my OP, I can now confirm that the firewall causing issues is ufw. How do I disable it/add appropriate rules for SSH. I need to edit the iptables directly via nano on Debian.

Comment: to completely disable ufw, just type `sudo ufw disable` make sure everything will be visible.

Comment: No, I need to disable it through the file structure. The only way to access my VPS is through a "Rescue-Mode" through my VPS provider. I need to either add the rules or disable the firewall through that.